# Popping and reordering a heap array by an element of an object in java

Tags: java, arrays, heap

The method that I'm having issues with is popTop
I have an OurProcess array that has a variable name currentPriority that I am sorting this heap from
smallest to largest but popTop just sends back the first object then leaves priorities[0] == null and I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class Queue {
int number1 = 0;
final int root = 0; // an easy reference to the root of the heap
int endPoint = 0; // Endpoint is where the first blank space in in queue is
int size; // an easier value to work with than the length of the array
OurProcess[] priorities; // The array that the whole class is built upon
char location; // This is just shorthand for the name of the object
Queue(int size, char location) {
    this.location = location;
    this.size = size;
    priorities = new OurProcess[size];
}

Queue(OurProcess[] processesArray, char location) throws Exception {
    this.location = location;
    size = processesArray.length;
    priorities = new OurProcess[processesArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < processesArray.length - 1; i++) {
        insert(processesArray[i]);
    }
}

public void insert(OurProcess toAdd) {

    if (endPoint == priorities.length) {
        System.out.println("Out of bounds");
    } else {
        endPoint++;
        priorities[endPoint - 1] = toAdd;
        siftUp(endPoint - 1);
    }
}

public void siftUp(int nodeIndex) {
    int parentIndex;
    OurProcess tmp;
    if (nodeIndex < priorities.length) {
        parentIndex = (nodeIndex - 1) / 2;
        while (priorities[parentIndex].currentPriority > priorities[nodeIndex].currentPriority) {
            tmp = priorities[parentIndex];
            priorities[parentIndex] = priorities[nodeIndex];
            priorities[nodeIndex] = tmp;
            siftUp(parentIndex);
        }

    }
}

public OurProcess popTop() {
    OurProcess pop = priorities[root]; // Copy the root of our array
    priorities[root] = priorities[endPoint]; // Place our object at the end
    priorities[endPoint] = null;
    int index = root;
    int leftChild = index*2+1;
    int rightChild, lesserChild;
        while(index < priorities.length && priorities[index] != null){
            lesserChild = leftChild;
            rightChild = leftChild + 1;
            if (priorities[rightChild].currentPriority < priorities[leftChild].currentPriority){
                lesserChild = rightChild;
            }
            if (priorities[lesserChild].currentPriority < priorities[index].currentPriority){
                OurProcess temp = priorities[lesserChild];
                priorities[lesserChild] = priorities[index];
                priorities[index] = temp;
                index = lesserChild;
                leftChild = index*2+1;
            }
        }


    return pop; // Return the top of the array
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you need a custom algorithm/datastructure for this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment here:

```
int endPoint = 0; // Endpoint is where the first blank space in in queue is
```

we can expect that `priorities[endPoint]` will always be null. So this:

```
    OurProcess pop = priorities[root]; // Copy the root of our array
    priorities[root] = priorities[endPoint]; // Place our object at the end
    priorities[endPoint] = null;
    int index = root;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
    OurProcess pop = priorities[root]; // Copy the root of our array
    priorities[root] = null;
    int index = root;
```

after which this:

```
       while(index < priorities.length && priorities[index] != null){
```

is equivalent to this:

```
       while(false){
```

I guess you actually meant to use `endPoint - 1` (the last non-null index) rather than `endPoint` (the first null index), but you also need to take much more care with edge-cases; for example, what if the heap is already empty when `popTop` is called?

Also, more importantly — you should learn to debug your code, either by using a debugger or by using `System.out.println(...)` statements to see what's going on at various points. Had you done that here, you would quickly have found what part of your code was not doing what you expected.